# Is this subspace isomorphic to $\ell^1$?

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space.

Suppose there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that for all finite $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ we have that $\|\sum_{n\in A}x_n\|$ equals the number of elements in $A$.

Does this imply that the subspace spanned by $\{x_n\}$ is isomorphic to $\ell^1$?

Comment: If $\sum_{n\in A} x_n$ equals the number of elements of $A$, the $x_n$ must be numbers and in fact $x_n=1$ (use the condition for singletons $A=\{n\}$).

Comment: @Jochen. Notice the norm now around $\sum_{n\in A}x_n$. Without this norm, this must be a number and indeed $x_n=1$ follows.

Comment: My comment was before your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order that the subspace spanned by $(x_n)$ is isomorphic to $l^1$  it has to be closed. Hence, we have to talk about the closure of the span of $(x_n)$.

If $X$ is reflexive, then this subspace is also reflexive, and cannot be isomorphic to $l^1$.

If $X$ is a Hilbert space (or strictly convex space) then no such sequence can exist.

Also the example by @Jochen ($X=\mathbb R^1$, $x_n=1$) shows that span of $(x_n)$ needs not to be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: But it is not clear that such a sequence exists in reflexive spaces.

Comment: @Carucel As you accepted the answer so quickly: What do I miss? Does, e.g., $\ell^2$ admit such a sequence?

Comment: Thank you for your interesting proof. Thank you also @Jochen for your very clever remark. The reason I accepted so quickly is that I was completely not expecting such a proof and was too easily convinced.

Comment: For any $x\in X$ with norm $1$, the constant sequence $x_n=x$ satisfies the requirement. This example, however, is cheated. It would be more interesting to have a linear independent sequence.

Comment: @Jochen $X=l^\infty$, $x_n= (1,...,1,0,0,...)$ with $n$ non-zero entries. Is the closure of the span equal to $c$?

Comment: Nice example @daw. The closed span of $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is equal to the closed spaan of $\{e_n: n\in\mathbb N\}$ (with the unit vectors $e_n=x_n-x_{n-1}$) and this is the space $c_0$ of sequences converging to $0$.

Comment: @daw: without considering the closure of its span, your example also shows that $\|\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^nx_n\|_{\ell^\infty}=1$, which makes it impossible for $\{x_n\}$ to be isomorphic to $\ell^1$, since $\|\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^ne_n\|_{\ell^1}=N$.