# Is this subspace isomorphic to the space $\ell^1$?

Tags: banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space.

Suppose there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ such that

- for all finite $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, and
- for all functions $\alpha:A\to\{-1,1\}$,

we have that $\|\sum_{n\in A}\alpha_nx_n\|$ equals the number of elements in $A$.

Does this imply that the closure of the subspace spanned by $\{x_n\}$ is isomorphic to $\ell^1$?

*This question is a modification to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121289/is-this-subspace-isomorphic-to-ell1) question, where $\alpha\equiv 1$.*

Comment: you talk about the closed subspace spanned by $\{ x_n \}$. Shouldn't it be the closure of the subspace spanned by $\{ x_n \}$ since you dont know if it is already closed?

Comment: @supinf yes thank you, that is what i meant

Comment: @supinf "Closed subspace spanned by" is a perfectly standard synonym for "closure of the subspace spanned by". More briefly, "closed span".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is true.
It is even possible to show more, namely that the closure of the span is isomtrically isomorphic to $\ell^1$.

The main part of the proof will be to show that
$$
 \tag{1}
 \label{eq1}
 \|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i\| = \sum_{i=1}^n | a_i|
$$
is true for all $(a_i)\in \ell^1$ and $n\in\mathbb N$.

We prove \eqref{eq1} by induction in $n$.

We assume that \eqref{eq1} was already shown for $n\in\mathbb N$
and we want to show that it also holds for $n+1$.
Wlog we can assume that $a_{n+1}\geq |a_i|$ for $i=1,\ldots n$
(Otherwise we can reorder the indices so that $|a_{n+1}|$
is coefficient with the largest absolute value,
and $a_{n+1}\geq0$ can be assumed because otherwise we can multiply everything by $-1$).

We define $\alpha_i:=\operatorname{sgn} a_i$.
Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
\|\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i x_i\|
&= 
\|a_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \alpha_i x_i - \sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i a_{n+1}-a_i)x_i\|
\\ &\geq 
\|a_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \alpha_i x_i\|-\| \sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i a_{n+1}-a_i)x_i\|
\\ &=
 |a_{n+1}|(n+1) - \sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha_i a_{n+1}-a_i|
\\ &=
 |a_{n+1}|(n+1) - \sum_{i=1}^n (|a_{n+1}|-|a_i|)
 = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} |a_i|.
\end{align}
$$
The other inequality follows from the triangle inequality.

Thus \eqref{eq1} holds true for all $n\in\mathbb N, (a_i)\in\ell^1$.
By continuity it can also be shown that \eqref{eq1} holds for $n=\infty$.

Let us define the map
$$
 I:\ell^1\to \overline{\operatorname{span}(x_i)},
 e_n\mapsto x_n.
$$
Then it follows from the above that $I$ is an isometry.
Finally, the property that $I$ is an isometry can be used to show that $I$ is surjective and injective.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why we are allowed to take $a_{n+1}\geq |a_i|$ for $i=1,\ldots n$?

Comment: We can reorder the indices if necessary. I edited.

Comment: I think you have made a mistake: why do you think that $\| \sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i a_{n+1}-a_i)x_i\|=\sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha_i a_{n+1}-a_i|$?

Comment: that is by induction assumption. We can use the formula (1) for this case.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Thank you very much. I found it hard to believe the statement you proved, since it is not true if we only know the assumption for $\alpha\equiv 1$ by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3121297/34067).